# можете подсказать где в коде ошибка?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
a = int(input())
while a != 0:
    if a > 0:
        print('Number is positive')
    elif a < 0:
        print('Number is negative')
else:
    print('Number is equal to zero')
    if a == 7:
        print('Good bye!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок тут куча. Будем исправлять поэтапно:

1. Куда у вас съехал последний else? Он же тоже по логике должен находиться в цикле while:

```
a = int(input())
while a != 0:
    if a > 0:
        print('Number is positive')
    elif a < 0:
        print('Number is negative')
    else:
        print('Number is equal to zero')
    if a == 7:
        print('Good bye!')
```

2. А где у вас следующий ввод числа? У вас число в программе вводится всего лишь один раз (в самом начале), а больше не вводится. Ввод числа лучше поместить в цикл:

```
a = None
while a != 0:
    a = int(input())
    if a > 0:
        print('Number is positive')
    elif a < 0:
        print('Number is negative')
    else:
        print('Number is equal to zero')
    if a == 7:
        print('Good bye!')
```

3. Почему прекращение программы у вас идёт на нуле, а не на 7. Я про условие цикла `while`, оно должно быть `a != 7`:

```
a = None
while a != 7:
    a = int(input())
    if a > 0:
        print('Number is positive')
    elif a < 0:
        print('Number is negative')
    else:
        print('Number is equal to zero')
    if a == 7:
        print('Good bye!')
```

И ещё момент, который бы хотелось уточнить по этой задаче: должна ли программа выводить, что 7 - положительное? Если да, то программа готова. Если нет, то проверку на равенство 7 надо поставить самым первым, а дальше использовать `elif`.

Comment: спасибо, за исправление и показ ошибок, буду стараться больше не допускать их

Answer (score 0):

Почему у вас условие else ушло куда-то? Поставьте его в нужное место и проверьте все ли окей